# My view is taking me to the same page over and over

Tags: django, django-views

Hey guys I made a model that can upload some files and then i made two views upload_list.html and upload_detail.html the list pages contains the links to the actual detail page but while clicking on the links it takes me to the same page again

Here,s the models.py

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images',)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'images/%Y/%M/%d/')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.pk{}
```

Here,s the views.py

```
def upload_list(request):

    upload_list = Upload.objects.all()


    return render(request,'app/upload_list.html',{'upload_list':upload_list})



def upload_detail(request,pk):

    upload_detail = get_object_or_404(Upload,pk = pk) 


    return render(request,'app/upload_detail.html',{'upload_detail':upload_detail})
```

Hers, the urls.py

```
url(r'^upload/',views.upload_list,name = 'upload_list'),

    url(r'^upload/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$',views.upload_detail,name = 'upload_detail'),
```

Hers, the upload_list.html

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% block content %}      
{% load static %}


{% for i in upload_list %}
<div class="jumbotron">

    <a href="{% url 'upload_detail' i.pk %}">{{i.name}}</a>
    <br>

</div>
 {% endfor %}





{% include 'app/index_js.html' %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Here,s the upload_Detail.html

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% block content %}      
{% load static %}


<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>{{upload_detail.name}}</h1>
    <img src="{{upload_detail.name}}" alt="'Image for you,r betterment "></img>

    {{upload_detail.file}}
</div>






{% include 'app/index_js.html' %}
{% endblock conten`t %}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried put your urls.py like this ?

```
url(r'^upload/$',views.upload_list,name = 'upload_list'),
url(r'^upload/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$',views.upload_detail,name = 'upload_detail'),
```

or

```
url(r'^upload/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$',views.upload_detail,name = 'upload_detail'),
url(r'^upload/$',views.upload_list,name = 'upload_list'),
```

The $ is a regex that indicates a end of string.

I hope that helps you